# trying to get this code to work so that when I press the Botton the servo rotates and then when I press again it moves

Tags: button, arduino, servo

I can't tell what's wrong with the code it just keeps telling me "Arduino: 1.8.19 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Uno"

sketch_jun16b:12:12: error: expected initializer before '.' token
int Myservo.write(0);
^
sketch_jun16b:13:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
{
^
exit status 1
expected initializer before '.' token"

```
#include<Servo.h>
Servo Myservo;
int pos=0;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(2,INPUT);
  Myservo.attach(3);
}

int Myservo.write(0);
{
  if(digitalRead(2)==LOW and Myservo.write(90){
    Myservo.write(0);
  }
  else

  if(digitalRead(2)==LOW and Myservo.write(90){
    Myservo.write(0);
}

void loop()
{
  if(digitalRead(2)==LOW){
    Myservo.write(90);
  }
  else

 Myservo.write(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
int Myservo.write(0);
{
  if(digitalRead(2)==LOW and Myservo.write(90){
    Myservo.write(0);
  }
  else

  if(digitalRead(2)==LOW and Myservo.write(90){
    Myservo.write(0);
}
```

is not inside a function, as it should be.  Is it supposed to be inside your loop() function?

The "and" function in C and C++ is `&&`.  So change

```
if(digitalRead(2)==LOW and Myservo.write(90){
```

to

```
if(digitalRead(2)==LOW && Myservo.write(90){
```